# Would you liketh a user icon in the style of my hat designs?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winterbash

In the spirit of the season, I grant-eth ye one wish-eth!

If any of our users think it would be cool, I'll do 10 user illustrations in the style of the Hats illustrated for the gaming site.

**First 10 people to claim it in comments get it!**

You can choose to either have your existing gravtar icon done, or send me a picture of yourself and I'll give it the treatment of ye old Hat Dash!

I think it is a great way to extend some holiday cheer and meet our users who are enjoying our Hat Dash :)

I'm not sure if the best way is to let you post images here or email me directly, but what say you users? Tell me how we should work it?

[image]
claim #1 filled.

[image]
For AshleyNunn

[image]
@ianPuglsey

[image]
Raven Dreamer

[image]
LessPop-MoreFizz

[image]
Agent86

[image]
Arda Xi

[image]
fallen Angel eyes

[image]
Master 69 Wraith

[image]
Jupotter

Comment: CLAIMED #1 (let's see what you make of this)

Comment: Sounds fun. I will claim one. :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn would you like to use your existing pic?

Comment: Hm. I am thinking of changing it in the next day or so - is that alright?

Comment: I'll claim one, despite the fact that my gravatar already depicts a monkey in a hat (a crown counts as a hat, right?).

Comment: I say crown is technically a hat.

Comment: I'm in! Remember - there are sharks in here!

Comment: I'm a person of my word, and all claims will be filled made thus far. @ashleyNunn is up next.

Comment: Reopened!  Seems fine to me (and pretty awesome), if Sean hasn't completely ragequit :\

Comment: If I'm not too late, Cartoon Dr. Teeth would be rad!

Comment: I can't keep straight how many have been claimed, but if there's still one or more left, sign me up please.  My current Gravatar works, if you'd like a SVG version I can post one somewhere, If I still have it...

Comment: so far the count is 1.AlexanderPas  2.Ashley Nunn  3.Ian Pugsley  4.Raven Dreamer  5.LessPop-MoreFizz   6.@agent86 (also the person with the most hats)  so there are 4 spots left.

Comment: @SeanGallagher I'll take one if you're still offering.

Comment: This looks fun! I'll take one! :D Though my gravatar's a fuzzy .gif when you resize it, apologies. >_>

Comment: @tzenes I'm not a random artist on the site, I'm art director for stackexchange. I created hat dash. This is a gift from stack exchange, on my behalf to grow and support the gaming site, specifically to the gaming users who are enjoying the hats. This is not a random discussion, it's a aspect of hat dash for improving our community and website together.

Comment: Really, we should give Sean a diamond. Just so he doesn't keep getting mistaken for one of the plebian "totally-not-a-part-of-the-stack-exchange-team" folks.

Comment: i would asketh thee for the fat man's red hat old santa himself sir with a gun in his right hand just like my jesus pic : P

Comment: @SeanGallagher I'd love to have one too, if there's still a spot left.

Comment: @Master69Wraith hmmmm, so santa with a gun? i know big faces like Badp and his icon really work well... maybe santa's face with bullet teeth?

Comment: @RavenDreamer thanks for your help. I'm looking forward to doing all sorts of different things and growing this site super moar.

Comment: @Jupotter you're in there...

Comment: @SeanGallagher I changed my avatar to the one I would like. It's pretty detailed (me and my cat) so feel free to pull whatever part of it you like for inspiration. :)

Comment: @SeanGallagher  Yes Santa With Bullit teeth would rock sir just love the theme : ) thank you very much a big wide grinning bullit toothed santa,lol

Comment: or better yet google Evil Inside logo,with the black background with red lettering and wrap around would be very uber for my sense of humor : )  and i won't look so much like Badp lol

Comment: @AshleyNunn great!

Comment: @Master69Wraith cool... I'll think of something festive / evil.

Comment: @AshleyNunn gravatar wish come true! (I hope at least)

Comment: @SeanGallagher I love it. It's awesome. :)

Comment: 21 comments; I assume it’s too late. `:)`

Comment: @SeanGallagher Any chance for some love for Philosoraptor?  If there's still a spot, I'd love to fill it!

Comment: A version of my current avatar if there is still a spot?

Comment: Jupotter is the last one I can commit to. If by some miracle I can bang out a few more, I will :) Thanks

Comment: making user icons for hatdash.com LOVE IT! Hope everyone likes these.

Comment: Oh, sweet raptor jesus. That is awesome.

Comment: So perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanGallagher, wow, just wow.  he looks epic with the wampa kappa hat on too :)

Comment: Glad everyone is enjoying this. :) Please remember to share our gaming site with other gamers and tell them to come get awesome with us!

Comment: seeing all the ones above you've done I'm waiting for mine like a little kid for X-mas :P

Comment: @ArdaXi done! Hope u like :)

Comment: @Master69Wraith come n get it !!!!

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes hope you don't hate me for taking such liberties.

Comment: @Jupotter 1 gray furry dog to go

Comment: @Sean haha, that's fine, though they're little wings above the eyes, not bushy eyebrows XD I admit it's hard to tell though!

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes  Well... you got a cyclops. Cyclops NEED big ol eyebrows... And there is FAE in the veins on the eyes.

Comment: @Sean Holy crap that's awesome, I didn't even notice that! +1 to your mad graffiti skills. :D

Comment: @SeanGallagher I made your shark rendition classier by adding a monocle and pipe to your work. Thoughts?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Mega classy!

Answer (score 5):

The Answer is YES!

[image]